# iOS SpriteKit - Creating physics for a bobblehead?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, physics

I am trying to create a realistic bobblehead app, and want to use physics for the bobble animation. I have seen other apps out there that do it, and from what I gather I need to use SpriteKit.

I have created a SKScene and used a SKPhysicsJointPin to pin the head to the body, but it doesnt move around at all. Any ideas or suggestions?

**UPDATED CODE (5/28):**

Now using 2 spring joints on the head and it moves left to right, but not up and down. Also, tapping quickly causes the head to eventually go far enough right to "fall of" and out of view. Weird.

**Have any ideas on what the proper setting would be to allow it to bobble up, down, left, and right whil staying remotely centered on it's starting position and staying within a specified region so it doesnt come off the body and look all funny?**

*BobbleheadView is a subclassed SKView*

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        self.showsFPS = YES;
        self.showsNodeCount = YES;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self
                                       action:@selector(animateBobble)];

        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        SKScene *bobbleheadScene = [SKScene sceneWithSize:self.bounds.size];
        [self presentScene:bobbleheadScene];

        // 1. Body
        self.body = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bobble-Body"];
        self.body.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.body.frame.size.height/2);
        self.body.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        [bobbleheadScene addChild:self.body];

        // 2. Head
        self.head = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Bobble-Head"];
        self.head.position = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.body.frame.size.height);
        //self.head.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
//        self.head.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        //This bobbles head great, but head falls off body and out of view
        self.head.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.head.size center:self.head.position];
        //End
        //self.head.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.head.frame];
        //self.head.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:self.head.size.height/2];
        [bobbleheadScene addChild:self.head];

        // 3. Ceiling
        self.ceiling = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(32, 32)];
        self.ceiling.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.origin.x+self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height);
        self.ceiling.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        [bobbleheadScene addChild:self.ceiling];



        //Spring Joint for Ceiling to Head
        SKPhysicsJointSpring *spring1 = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:self.ceiling.physicsBody bodyB:self.head.physicsBody anchorA:self.ceiling.position anchorB:CGPointMake(self.head.frame.origin.x+self.head.frame.size.width/2, 0)];

        spring1.frequency = 20.0; //gives the spring some elasticity.
        spring1.damping = 5.0; //Will remove damping to create the 'pendulum'
        [bobbleheadScene.physicsWorld addJoint:spring1];


        //Spring Joint for Head to Body
        SKPhysicsJointSpring *spring = [SKPhysicsJointSpring jointWithBodyA:self.body.physicsBody bodyB:self.head.physicsBody anchorA:CGPointMake(self.body.position.x+self.body.size.width/2, self.body.position.y) anchorB:CGPointMake(self.head.position.x+self.head.size.width/2, self.body.position.y-self.body.size.height/2)];

        spring.frequency = 10.0; //gives the spring some elasticity.
        spring.damping = 1.0;
        [bobbleheadScene.physicsWorld addJoint:spring];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)animateBobble{
    NSLog(@"Did Tap Bobblehead!");
    [self.head.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(100, -200)];
    //[self.body.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(20, 10)];
}
```

Comment: The joint anchorpoint should probably be somewhat closer towards the body.

Comment: Ok, little closer now. I set the anchor to 'self.body.position', but now the head loops around in a big circle.

Comment: Add a spring joint to hold the head upright and give it a wobbly feel. The spring connects to a static body at the location about where the head is centered (or perhaps more towards the top of the head), the other ends of the spring connect to the head. As it rotates the spring will try to bring the head back to the upgright position.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Do you have any good/simple documentation on Spring Joints? Or a code example? SpriteKit is all new to me..

Comment: In that case: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SpriteKitFramework_Ref/_index.html and the guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Ok, I am so close! I updated the code, I think I just need to figure out the proper SKPhysicsBody setting for the head. Can you point me in the right direction so the head will be able to bobble up, down, left, and right while staying remotely centered on it's starting position?

Comment: experiment with multiple spring joints, consider how you would do that in real life to a ball on a pole with just rubber bands (and 2 dimensions) ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54348/discussion-between-james-hickman-and-learncocos2d).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have been playing around a bit and setup 2 spring joints anchored at the top of the view to the top of the head, and the bottom of the body and bottom of the head. The head now sits on the body properly and swings left to right, but can't get it to move up and down at all. I have played around with the 2 springs' frequencies and damping controls, but still no luck. So very close! Any suggestions? Code updated on OP

Answer (score 5):

The only way you'll get this to work is to **make a "sled".**

So: make an app where, on screen there are (say) six sliders.

TBC I mean, when the app is actually running, you'll see six sliders.

TBC, this is only **a sled**, it's only for you as a developer, it's not for the consumer app.

(I believe the term "sled" comes from the automotive industry; when they make the first version of a chassis/engine to test it out.)

Make it so that some sliders control spring power/damp (or whatever factors you have available in cocos) and that other sliders nudge the position of the connections/spring lengths.

it's the only way to get a result!  Be sure to show the values on screen, or at least print them out on the console as they change.

This is the everyday thing in game development. *Typically the sled is more work than the actual consumer scene or feature.* You won't be able to achieve it without a "sled". I hope it helps!

Comment: +1 just to add... This is exactly how the "Springboard jiggle" was created. Steve jobs was given an iOS installation with sliders on for various values and he adjusted it to get it "just right". The engineers then hard coded these values in for the actual build of iOS.

Comment: Right!!!!!!!!  that's a great example, Fog!!!!  Like I mention, the sleds are  often, indeed usually, far far more complicated than the actual game in question.  The sleds for things like race games and fighting games are mammoth 747-simuilator like things. This is literally the answer to James' question.  Epic example, Fog.